# Dynamicly Added Input is not updating on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am new to JavaScript so bear with me here.

I have this code below that checks a text input fields value, if it matches then I fire off my Custom Dialog object/function which shows a Dialog modal window.

Now my goal is to Clear out the text input that fired the Dialog to open if the `Cancel` button is clicked

I have a Callback function named `cancelCallback` that I can pass into my Dialog function.

In my example you can see I have cached the Input field selector `hostnameSelector` and then passed it into my callback.

Below that you can see I print out the object to the Console.  The Console shows my NEW value for the text field but it does not update on the screen.

This could be possibly because the Text Input filed is Dynamicly added to the screen/DOM?

Any ideas on how I can get it working?  I am also able to use the latest jQuery if needed to help

```
// Show Notice if Hostname Matches the Domain Name
$(document).on('change','div.hostName > input',function() {

    // cached Input Selector
    var hostnameSelector = $(this);

    var hostName = $(this).val();
    var domainName = $("#domainName").val();
    var pattern = new RegExp(domainName + "$","g");
    if ( hostName.match(pattern) != null ) {

        var msg = 'Are you sure you want to delete action?';

        zPanel.dialog.confirm({
            heading: 'ATTENTION',
            message: msg,
            width: 300,
            cancelCallback: function (hostname) {
                    hostnameSelector .value = 'hi';
                    console.log(hostnameSelector);
            },
            cancelButton: {text: 'Cancel', show: true, class: 'btn-default'},
            okButton: {text: 'Confirm', show: true, class: 'btn-primary'},
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CancelCallback should set the new value by calling:

```
hostnameSelector.val("hi")
```

Comment: Thank you, im glad it was a simple mistake